Sympy equation simplify does not get rid of fractions. Is there an easy way to do it?
I am running code containing something like the below:
import sympy
eq_lhs = sympy.sympify("2*x - 3*y + 43/2")
my_eq = sympy.Eq(eq_lhs, rhs=0)
my_eq.simplify()
print(my_eq)

The output is still
2*x - 3*y + 43/2 = 0

Whereas I expect the fraction(s) to be factored out, as such:
4*x - 6*y + 43 = 0

Is there a certain sympy feature that would do this? Should .simplify() do this already? I'd like your input.
I have a new manual function made now for this, but I was just wondering if this is something that should be the default already.
def my_simplify(eq):
    # Extract the denominators of the coefficients
    dens_lhs = [sympy.fraction(term)[1] for term in eq.lhs.as_ordered_terms()]
    dens_rhs = [sympy.fraction(term)[1] for term in eq.rhs.as_ordered_terms()]
    lcm = sympy.lcm(dens_lhs + dens_rhs)

    # Multiply the entire equation by the LCM
    simplified_eq = sympy.Eq(lcm * eq.lhs, lcm * eq.rhs)

    # Return
    return simplified_eq


my_simplify() is just fine. simplify() doesn't do that.

primitive will give you the content and the content-free expression:
>>> from sympy import primitive, S
>>> eq=S("2*x - 3*y + 43/2")
>>> content(eq)
1/2
>>> primitive(eq)
(1/2, 4*x - 6*y + 43)


what do you mean by content?

The content of a polynomial is the common gcd of its coefficients. The primitive part of a polynomial is the polynomial divided by its content so that the gcd of the coefficients is 1. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_part_and_content
